# Does G Suite's "Ask the user to change password" work with the "Automatically generate" option?

Tags: g-suite-administrator

When adding a new user to G Suite, you can:

> - Create a password: Automatically generate it or enter one here.
>
> ...
>
> - (Optional) Ask the user to change this password the next time they
>     sign in.
>
> <sub>-https://support.google.com/a/answer/33310</sub>

But if you choose **Automatically generate** then **Ask the user to...** is grayed out as **No**.

Does it mean the user **won't** get asked to change their automatic password?

I assume there are 2 possible answers here:

1. No, the user will just keep the generated password.
2. Yes, the user will be forced to change the generated password, and Google actually meant to gray out a **Yes** choice rather than a **No** one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's indeed a visual bug in Google.

When you choose **Automatically generate** then **Ask the user to...** is supposed to be grayed out as **Yes**, because that's exactly what it does.

I wonder what is the chance of Google fixing it to display correctly.

Comment: Great catch! _"I wonder what is the chance of Google fixing it to display correctly."_. Well.....